# How to get wifi SSID on api 27 (android 8.1)?

Tags: android

I want to get the name of connected WiFi in Android 8.1. When I get the SSID it returns "unknown ssid". Some answers on Stack-overflow say to get Location permissions. I even did that, but the issue persists. but when I switch on the location icon in the phone drop down menu（just like open GPS or Network location）, it works fine. But I think it's too much trouble to open the positioning in the system settings. Is there anyway to get ssid without manually opening location like that? Or can I open the positioning just in my app?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return getString(R.string.grant_location_permission_wifi_name)
    }
}

val wifiInfo = mWifiManager.connectionInfo.ssid
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult#SSID ...asking how to get it on Oreo does not really make sense, because nothing had ever changed. `ScanResult` is available since API level 1.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I added some references to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075472/2297684), some API levels actually have this issue, so the OP is not wrong

Answer (score 0):

As of now, permission itself is not enough, location services have to be enabled to use `WifiManager.getScanResults` and `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo`.

There's an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37060483) about this in the AOSP tracker and it is not yet fixed.
You can actually see people [mentioning](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37060483#comment29) removed devs' posts about fixing this issue for tartgetSdk < 23 which didn't actually fix it anyway.

For the reference: [`enforceCanAccessScanResults`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/pie-release/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/util/WifiPermissionsUtil.java#183) checks if location is enabled:

```
public void enforceCanAccessScanResults(String pkgName, int uid) 
                                            throws SecurityException {
    ...
    // Location mode must be enabled
    if (!isLocationModeEnabled()) {
        // Location mode is disabled, scan results cannot be returned
        throw new SecurityException("Location mode is disabled for the device");
    }
    ...
}
```

And it is called in the `WifiManager`'s [`getScanResults`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/pie-release/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiServiceImpl.java#2038):

```
@Override
public List<ScanResult> getScanResults(String callingPackage) {
    ...
    try {
        //this checks permissions and location mode
        mWifiPermissionsUtil.enforceCanAccessScanResults(callingPackage, uid);
        ...
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        return new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
    } 
    ...
}
```

**TLDR**
The location services have to be turned on to get the network's SSID,
if it's off so you can either promt user to change location settings [like this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings#prompt) (better UX) or you can redirect user to the settings page:

```
Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
```

As the last option, you can try using `ConnectivityManager`'s `getActiveNetworkInfo`:

```
    val cm = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, ConnectivityManager::class.java)

    val ssid: String? = cm?.activeNetworkInfo?.extraInfo
```

Comment: thanks, but how to enable the location service? can I enable it in my code?

Comment: I know tartgetSdk < 23 works, but now publish or update App in Google Play Store requires targetSdk >= 26

Comment: it works and I knew it can work.Although it is not the answer I want, thank you for giving me some information about this issue. 
In fact, there is an app named "EZVIZ" that don't need to manually open the location service, just need to give the location permission , and then it gets the correct WIFISSID, 
I don't know how they did it. SO I post here to ask for help.  thanks.

Comment: the last one you post is not a conventional way, for some devices in android 8.1 are ok, but is not ok for android 9.0.  thank you very much.